# Protocol Violation Exception when using GetResponse()

Tags: c#, powerbi

I Have been trying to follow Dev Power BI instructions to create a Datatset from my Consol App but Keep getting the following Exception:

"You must write ContentLength bytes for the request stream before calling [Begin] GetResponse".
Bellow are the written codes.

```
             private static void CreateDataset()
    {
        string PowerBIDatasetsApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets";

        HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(PowerBIDatasetsApiUrl) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        request.Headers.Add("Autorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", token));


        string datasetJson = "{\"name\": \"SalesMarketing\", \"tables\": " +
            "[{\"name\": \"product\", \"columsa\":" +
            "[{\"name\": \"productID\", \"dataType\": \"Int64\"}, " +
            "[{\"name\": \"category\", \"dataType\": \"string\"}, " +
            "[{\"name\": \"IsCompete\", \"dataType\": \"bool\"}, " +
            "[{\"name\": \"ManufacturedOn\", \"dataType\": \"DateTime\"}" +
            "]}]}";

        byte[] byteAray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(datasetJson);
        request.ContentLength = byteAray.Length;

        using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
        {

            writer.Write(byteAray, 0, byteAray.Length);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Dataset {0}", response.StatusCode.ToString()));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try calling `writer.Flush()` after your call to `Write` to make sure all of the data has been written to the stream.

Comment: Just did , but unfortunately for me, it is not helping.